# How do I check for an error in bash with -e

Tags: bash, error-handling

How can I selectively check lines for errors (and not fail) when `-e` is set.

Most of my commands need `-e`, but one does not.

```
set -e
foo
bar

biz
if [ ! $? -e 0 ]
   echo oh noes
fi
```

The `$?` obviously doesn't work.

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the (4.1) `bash` man page for the `-e` option:

> The shell does not exit if the command that fails  is  part
>                         of  the command list immediately following a while or until keyword, part of the test following the if or elif reserved words, part of any command executed in
>                         a && or ││ list except the command following the final && or ││

```
biz || echo "oh noes"
```

Only if `biz` fails does the RHS of the `||` execute, and `echo` is guaranteed to exit with status 0 so it cannot cause your script to fail.

You can also run the command with an `if` statement, as suggested by Etan:

```
if ! biz; then
    echo "oh noes"
fi
```

You can also simply turn `-e` off temporarily:

```
set +e
biz
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
   echo oh noes
fi
set -e
```

Answer (score 2):

Inline the command running into the `if` check.

```
if ! biz; then
    echo oh noes
fi
```